# Adapt content to screen size (UWP app)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I am developing a uwp app and I am using the template 10. And I have this code already done:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for narrow view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="stateTextBox.Text" Value="Narrow Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for normal view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="stateTextBox.Text" Value="Normal Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for wide view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="stateTextBox.Text" Value="Wide Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And I'm setting up the present ads in the app. On the desktop I want to:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                          AdUnitId="test"
                          RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                          RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                          Margin="0,25,0,0"
                          Height="90"
                          Width="728"/>
```

And on mobile like this:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                          AdUnitId="test"
                          RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                          RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                          Margin="0,25,0,0"
                          Height="50"
                          Width="300"/>
```

How do I change the sizes of desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 2 choices you can use Adaptive or you have use Device-Family Views

The adaptive would be my choice and just use setters for the control.  Give the adcontrol a name then in the setters you will have something like

```
  <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="GUID" AdUnitId="Test" 
               Name="SomeAdControl" ... />     


  <!-- narrow -->
 <VisualState.Setter>
   <Setter Target="SomeAdControl.Width" Value="300" />
   <Setter Target="SomeAdControl.Height" Value="50" />
 <VisualState.Setter/>

 <!--- Normal -->
 <VisualState.Setter>
   <Setter Target="SomeAdControl.Width" Value="768" />
   <Setter Target="SomeAdControl.Height" Value="90" />
 </VisualState.Setter>
```

It is the same control with different dimensions according to the VisualTrigger that triggered.

Second option was Device-Family views, for example you could create folders for the separation or you can create Views specific in this case

```
  MainPage.DeviceFamily-Mobile.xaml
  MainPage.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml
  MainPage.xaml
```

all of which would be partials, with different views layouts. Or name the folder 
      DeviceFamily-Mobile and place a partial class MainPage.xaml in that folder